# Make program that prints month name according to corresponding number shorter

Tags: java

This program asks a user to input any number equal to or between 1-12. It then converts the number to a message that will be printed (Copy the program to see it yourself). Is there a way to make the code shorter?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumOfMonth {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    int num = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter any number equal to or between 1-12 to display the month"));

    switch (num)
    {
    case 1:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 1 is January");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 2 is February");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 3 is March");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 4 is April");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 5 is May");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 6 is June");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 7 is July");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 8 is August");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 9 is September");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 10 is October");
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 11 is November");
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println ("The name of month number 12 is December");
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println ("You have entered an invalid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your program works, and you're looking for a review, it may be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also you could look into an `enum` or an `Array` or a `Map`..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using [`DateFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html):

```
return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[num - 1];
```

[`getMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths--) returns array of months strings..

I highly encourage you to check for bounds before accessing the array.

Comment: Catching out-of-bounds values should not be omitted.

Comment: Sophisticated readers should notice that this method varies return values depending on the effective Locale setting.

Comment: Of course - just to let 'em know it's not a 1:1 simplification.

Answer (score 3):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] months = new String[]{
            "",
            "JAN",
            "FEB",
            "MAR",
            "APR",
            "MAY",
            "JUN",
            "JUL",
            "AUG",
            "SEP",
            "OCT",
            "NOV",
            "DEC"
        };

        int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any number equal to or between 1-12 to display the month"));

        if (num >= 1 && num <= 12) {
            System.out.println("Name of month is " + months[num]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
        }
    }
}
```